# Spaces while editing Dojo Enhanced Grid

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have been to one of the major problem in Dojo Enhanced grid for days. What i am trying to do is to disable default onApplyCellEdit event in spacebar press and act as normal spacebar as in text editor. Right now, spacebar press triggers onApplyCellEdit in first and onRowClick in second. I have researched it for days and also found some answers but those all didn't helped me.

Any solutions would be great help.

Thank You..

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. It is difficult to assess an issue without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it somehow, but i don't know whether it is appropriate way or not. There seems no service/way dojo have provided to change their enhancedgrid default behavior. Therefore, i directly did some modification in their library file (_FocusManager) and solved this problem. It has been tested and seems to be working fine till now.